# Unable to configure gnus with openmailbox server

Tags: gnus, email

I want to use gnus for reading and sending mails from my openmailbox address via IMAP, but can't configure it properly.

In /.gnus.el I wrote

```
(setq user-mail-address "email@openmailbox.org"
      user-full-name    "My Name")

(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "openmailbox"
           (nnimap-address "imap.openmailbox.org")
           (nnimap-server-port "imaps")
           (nnimap-stream ssl)
           (nnimap-authinfo-file "/home/user/.authinfo.gpg")))

(setq smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.openmailbox.org"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
```

and in /.authinfo.gpg

```
machine imap.openmailbox.org login <LOGIN> password <PASSWORD> port imaps
machine smtp.openmailbox.org login <LOGIN> password <PASSWORD> port 465
```

but when I'm trying to log in it gives me the following error

> nnimap (openmailbox) open error: 'NO (AUTHENTICATIONFAILED)
>   Authentication failed.' Continue? (y or n)

I also tried with port 587 but it fails with the same output.

Can anybody help me to configure gnus? You can find all necessary protocols on [openmailbox](https://www.openmailbox.org/) website.

Comment: In recent versions of Emacs, the variable `nnimap-authinfo-file` no longer exists. The variable `auth-sources` replaces it: See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusAuthinfo  However, the replacement is not a string -- instead, it is a list of one or more strings.  To learn more about said variable, type `M-x describe-variable RET auth-sources RET`.

Comment: You have defined the machine name as "openmailbox" as part of the `gnus-select-method`, so there is no corresponding entry in the `.authinfo.gpg` file.  I.e., your machine names in the `.authinfo.gpg` file are `imap.openmailbox.org` and `smtp.openmailbox.org`.  Perhaps also consider setting the `nnimap-server-port` to 993 and you can remove `port imaps` from the `.authinfo.gpg` file.  The openmailbox is refusing to permit new registrations, so unless someone has an existing account, settings cannot be tested.